# MVVM detailedpage navigation

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am not entirely sure how to explain this, the best way I can is the DataBoundApp in the windows phone 8 templates, when the user navigates to the detailed page of a listbox item, I want the user to be able to navigate through all the items by swiping left or right. I am not entirely sure where to begin with this, or how to search for this online.

[image: navigate from this page to page 2 and the other page also]

Answer (score 0):

i dont Clearly understand your question but if you want that the user can scroll all the items by scrolling left or right then u have 2 option either use Panaroma View or the Pivot View they both will do the same with some changes in the transition .....

Answer (score 0):

I got it, was searching for dynamically adding items to a panorama control, so the user can navigate through the list of items without him knowing how many their are, excellent tutorial:

http://www.felinesoft.com/blog/index.php/2010/12/dynamic-panorama-control-wp7-basics/